# Does the series $\sum 2^n \sin(\frac{\pi}{3^n})$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Check if $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}2^n \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3^n}\right)$$ converges.

I tried to solve this by using the ratio  test - I have ended up with the following limit to evaluate: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)} \right)$$
And now - I am stuck and don't know how to proceed with this limit. Any hints?

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin(x) \leq x$

Comment: L'Hospital's rule will help you with the limit you pose, but you can show convergence directly as Olivier outlines.

Comment: @Malcolm This is a sequence, not a function. A sequence is not differentiable.

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^x} \right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^x} \right)} \right)$ exists (which it does) then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)} \right)$ also exists and equals the same value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. One has
$$
\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3^n}\right)\right|\le\frac{\pi}{3^n},\quad n=1,2,\cdots.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Your observation implies that this limit in question - say, L: 
$$0 \le L \le 2/3$$ and so this series does converge?

Comment: You then have $$\left|\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}2^n \sin \frac{\pi}{3^n} \right| \le \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left|2^n \sin \frac{\pi}{3^n} \right| \le \pi \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n}<\infty$$ and the given series is **absolutely convergent** then it is **convergent**.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$2^n \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3^n}\right) \sim \pi\frac{2^n}{3^n}$$

then use **comparison test** with $$\sum \frac{2^n}{3^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your approach using the ratio test, you can *(although [Olivier's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2615302/75808) is more direct).* Caveat: I'll detail *every step* of the derivation, which is not actually necessary for a proof.

We will only rely on elementary arguments, specifically the fact that $\sin'(0)=\cos 0 = 1$ — which is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 \,.\tag{1}
$$
From there, you can write
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} 2\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n}}\cdot\frac{\frac{\pi}{3^n}}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)}
= \frac{2}{3}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n}}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)}{\frac{\pi}{3^n}}\right)^{-1} \tag{2}
$$
and, by (1), we get
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)}
&=
\frac{2}{3}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n}}\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)}{\frac{\pi}{3^n}}\right)^{-1}
=\frac{2}{3}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n} \right)}{\frac{\pi}{3 \cdot 3^n}}\cdot \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3^n} \right)}{\frac{\pi}{3^n}}\right)^{-1}  \\
&= \frac{2}{3}\cdot 1\cdot 1^{-1} = \boxed{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{align*}$$
and you can conclude with the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as Olivier express in a different way, you know that
$$
\sin\left(x\right)\underset{(0)}{=}x+o\left(x\right)
$$
Hence

> $$
> 2^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3^n}\right) \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\pi \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n
> $$

What can you say about $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 0}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ ?